# Best practice for CSS3 backgrounds and support for older browsers?

Tags: css

My colleague and I are having a tough time deciding on a best practices approach for ie6, ie7 support for a site we're building.  The site is for an older crowd, so not supporting these browsers is out of the question.

At the same time, we're trying to start incorporating modern coding practices into our work so we can get practice and fully understand capabilities.  A specific area I want to touch on with you guys is handling fall backs for CSS3 backgrounds.

We have 2 choices here, if we're to use CSS3 backgrounds and not add extraneous wrapping tags for backgrounds:

- Use :after, :before etc. pseudo elements for adding multiple backgrounds to elements. (this is the choice we've made for now)
- Use CSS3 multiple background specifications

This produces more elegant markup and is certainly a step in the right direction.  But what about browsers that don't support these features?

[Modernizr.js](http://modernizr.com) tells us to check for specific support and then write fallbacks:

```
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.geolocation,
  yep : 'geo.js',
  nope: 'geo-polyfill.js'
});
```

However, we're not given much guidance on the actual fallbacks for specific features.  So, in the case of something like CSS3 backgrounds, what would be an effective fallback strategy?

Would we (for example) use jQuery to wrap those extra tags we need (ie btn-container, nav-container, etc.) around nav items, buttons and containers in order to have extra elements to add style attributes to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the CSS3 `multiple backgounds` and/or `background gradients` I think there is an approach better than those you proposed: [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

This way you will be able to use all those nice effects also in IE6, 7 and 8 (including also `border-radious`) *without any JavaScript intervention*.

Comment: How's the perf on CSS3Pie these days? I attempted to use the first release (maybe it was tagged a beta) pretty heavily in an application UI and found that greater than ~50 VML instances on a page could really bog down the browser.

Comment: I haven't used it on + than ~15 elements at the same time, but is at least expected since the rendering engine of those older browsers was not created for this kind of complexity. But I think the current version do a nice job about performance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Erick.  This is looking like a good solution = )  For the most part, we're dropping features in ie6, but there were a couple features (like backgrounds) that would totally maul everything if we didn't support them.

Answer (score 2):

**1.  Fail gracefully.**  Certain complex elements can be hidden with CSS and revealed upon page-load with JavaScript depending on the browser as one example.

**2.  Conditional style-sheets or JavaScript fixes.**  Spend a lot of time fixing each problem in each browser and write a style-sheet just for it.  Also, you could try various JavaScripts that claim to bring older browsers into compliance.  I've tried **[this JavaScript](http://www.charlescooke.me.uk/web/lab_notes/ie7_script.html)** but it seemed to conflict with jQuery.  **[CSS Pie](http://css3pie.com/)** is another option to bring rounded corners to older browsers.

**3.  Ignore older browsers.**  Do nothing special for older browsers.  People on IE6/7 already see the world differently than everyone else.  Alternatively, do nothing special for older browsers but actively avoid overly complex functions & features.  Optionally, you can add a nifty **["upgrade notification" message](http://ie6update.com/)** with little effort.

Answer (score 1):

> Would we (for example) use jQuery to wrap those extra tags we need (ie btn-container, nav-container, etc.) around nav items, buttons and containers in order to have extra elements to add style attributes to?

That is certainly one valid fallback approach. Depending on the design and the elements in question, though, you might find that simply supplying the primary background is enough to yield a decent-looking and perfectly functional, though not visually identical, component.

"Supporting" older browsers shouldn't always mean "taking great pains/writing tons of extra code to insure a near visual match." It is difficult but not impossible to ramp up a QA team so that they understand the concept of Progressive Enhancement as it can be applied to aspects of pure visual presentation.